# Data storing design - ~400 events every 30 minutes

Tags: database-design

currently, I struggle with the design of an event monitor for my small project. I need to store ~400 events every 30 minutes (so every 30 minutes there are 400 events created and should be written at once). Later, I need to work with data and compare two or more data sets between each other (30 minutes / one data set) and perform some calculations (count, average value etc.).

Example data:

```
timestamp; temperature; amount
1618235499; 27.1; 300
1618235499; 27.2; 120
1618235499; 27.3; 12
```

Is it the best way how to do it storing inside one table in the database and select only needed data via SQL commands later?

Maybe using database is not the best way (but I need persistency).

Thank you in advance for any comments and suggestions

Comment: Do you get all 400 events at once, or are they spread out over the 30 minute period?  With the limited information you've provided in your question, all I can advise is to check out the Wikipedia article [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc 400 events at once, every 30 minutes period.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc But from you have written, do you think the only way is using database for this task?

Comment: What fields / variables does an event consist of?  Without that information, I can't comment further.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thanks for helping me to improve the question. I have added example data.

Comment: Ok.  400 events every 30 minutes is 19,200 events a day, or roughly 7,008,000 events a year.  Unless you need access to individual events, I'd just store the events in log files.  Each log file could contain a day's worth or a month's worth of events, depending on how you usually process the event information.